# accidentally removed folder as a root

Tags: root, delete, trash

I did `sudo -i`  and `rm -r folder` ...I typed the wrong folder and deleted a folder I didnt want to delete. Bad practice I know :( Where did the folder end up? Any chance of retrieve?
I am not sure where is the trash folder that the folder ended up in. I checked this site and some say that trash root is located at  `/root/.local/share/Trash` but this folder does not exists on my Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: `rm` does not move files or folders to a temporary place before deleting them permanently. If you are using an SSD, the directory is as good as gone. Grab a backup and restore. If you’re using a spinning disk, shut the machine down immediately and make an image via a Live USB, which you then use a utility like TestDisk on to try and recover data 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to reverse an rm command is to debug file system, method depends on the file system itself but also of your exact knowledge of what exactly  has been removed.

There is no exception to that but using external/installed dedicated tools before you need it.

In your case, you can only get it back from the file system method or from a previous backup.

you can read this topic : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files

Answer (score 1):

There is no trash folder for the command line. The folder did not end up anywhere. It is gone. The `rm` command removed it definitely. Your only chance is to recover it from a backup.